# Place items in dict from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If I have file like this:

```
1000:80
200:90
400:60
```

How would I place these values in a dict? Like this:

```
 d = {'1000':80, '200:90', '400':60}
```

Comment: My first comment is check that your `d={...}` is correctly written - some of the numbers are actually strings, and that second entry doesn't look valid at all (I mean, it could be if it was a set, but you can't mix dictionary and set notations)

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that this question exists on SO, maybe as two separate questions (how to read from file, how to build dictionary iteratively, maybe?) If you added to the bottom - "I've tried XY for reading data from a file from <this post> but Z problem occurs?" I'd be happy to help you finish up the last steps of the problem : ) Also, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this (using [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) and [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)):

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    my_dict = {x: int(v) for x, v in (line.split(":") for line in f)}

print(my_dict)
```

> {'200': 90, '400': 60, '1000': 80}